# The wrapped line is not displayed NavigationView android?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/appWhite"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemBackground="@color/appWhite"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

 <include layout="@layout/ads_footer" />
 </LinearLayout>
 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:showIn="navigation_view">


<item android:title="">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_create"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_create_menu"
        android:title="@string/navcreate" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_scancamera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_scan_menu"
        android:title="@string/navscan" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_scan_gallery"
        android:title="@string/navscangallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_menu"
        android:title="@string/navfavorite" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_menu"
            android:title="@string/navhistory" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Rate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate"
        android:title="@string/rate" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:title="@string/share" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_About"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
        android:title="@string/about" />
    <!--<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback"
        android:title="@string/feedback" />-->

  </item>

 </menu>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue that you're facing?